# Dimension of $X/Y$ when $dim X$ is infinite.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a $\mathbb K-$ linear space and $Y\subseteq X$ be a subspace. Let us define $X/Y=\{x+Y:x\in X\}.$ Then with the operations $$(a+Y)+(b+Y)=(a+b)+Y$$ $$\alpha (a+Y)=\alpha a +Y$$

$X/Y$ is a $\mathbb K$-linear space.

Now we know that if $\dim X<\infty$ then $\dim (X/Y)=\dim X-\dim Y$. But if $\dim X=\infty$ then what can we say about the dimension of $X/Y$?

Comment: Do you know how to derive the formula $\dim (X / Y) = \dim X - \dim Y$? You must have done it with the rank nullity theorem. Unfortunately that doesn't apply in infinite dimensions, but this map is crucial in telling you whether $X/Y$ is finite dimensional or not.

Comment: You can still say $\dim(Y)+\dim(X/Y)=\dim (X)$, but if $\dim(X)=\infty$, $\dim(Y)$ can be either finite or infinite, in which case so can $\dim(X/Y)$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  I didn't get what you said by 'this map is crucial...'

Comment: @mathiu_lady If you know what the "canonical " map  $X \to X/Y$ given by $x \to x+Y$ is, then you know whether or not $X/Y$ is finite dimensional or not. An example is when $Y = X$, then this map $x \to x+Y$ goes to precisely one element, so you can conclude that $X/Y$ is zero dimensional. In short, if the map has finite rank, then since it is onto $X/Y$ has finite dimension. Note that I am saying nothing extraordinary, but just extending the argument to infinite dimensions.